# AngularJS Prefetch data from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngtable

Is there any way in AngularJS to prefetch the data from url. I heard of template cache. Can template cache load the contents from path ?
I have created a directive, But I am facing problems. When I am using template, preloading the html, but when I am using templateURL, it's not preloading the html from path, only loading when it's needed. But I need data to be preloaded. Is that possible ?

```
cmsApp.directive('ptnPopup', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        template: '<div>{{bid}}</div>',
       //templateUrl: './template/popups/primary_trading_name.html',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.bid = 5;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: as i understand do you want to preload template into cache?

Comment: Yes, exactly I need to prefetch the html..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most hands-off approach for this is to introduce a task into your project that generates templates cache based on your templates.

like https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates

It will essentially generate a js file based on your templates that will preload all of them into $templatecache. Once this js is loaded, no further ajax requests will be made to your templates and you can keep using templateURL syntax in your directive definitions.

```
angular.module('app').run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("home.html",
    // contents for home.html ...
  );
  ...
  $templateCache.put("src/app/templates/button.html",
    // contents for button.html
  );
}]);
```

Comment: I am using templateURL in my directive and it's fetching the data from path "/template/popups/primary_trading_name.html" only when it's needed, but what I want is html should be prefetched from this path..

Comment: @VishalKhode that is EXACTLY the solution i proposed. grunt-angular-templates grunt plugin allows you to prefetch any templates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you see my above code, why it's not working. I am seeing output as {{bid}}, i should see output as 5..

Comment: If My answer answered your original question, please mark it as so

Comment: to answer your next question id need to see a plunkr example -- i have no idea how you use your directive or what MainCtrl does.